# Given a number give all possible combination of matching alphabet letter

Tags: c#, .net, numbers, combinations, permutation

Given the letter to number conversion where `a` is 1, `b` is 2, and so on...
A word can be converted to digits, and those digits can be concatenated to form a number:

```
dog   → 4|15|7  → 4157
```

I want to do the reverse operation and for one number create the list of possible preimage *words*:

```
512   → 5|1|2   → eab
        5|12    → el

4157  → 4|1|5|7 → daeg
      → 4|15|7  → dog
```

My attempts so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace NumberToWords
{
    public class Data
    {
        public IDictionary<int, string> listOfAlphabets;
        public Data()
        {
            listOfAlphabets = new Dictionary<int, string>();
            listOfAlphabets.Add(1, "A");
            listOfAlphabets.Add(2, "B");
            listOfAlphabets.Add(3, "C");
            listOfAlphabets.Add(4, "D");
            listOfAlphabets.Add(5, "E");
            listOfAlphabets.Add(6, "F");
            listOfAlphabets.Add(7, "G");
            listOfAlphabets.Add(8, "H");
            listOfAlphabets.Add(9, "I");
            listOfAlphabets.Add(10, "J");
            listOfAlphabets.Add(11, "K");
            listOfAlphabets.Add(12, "L");
            listOfAlphabets.Add(13, "M");
            listOfAlphabets.Add(14, "N");
            listOfAlphabets.Add(15, "O");
            listOfAlphabets.Add(16, "P");
            listOfAlphabets.Add(17, "Q");
            listOfAlphabets.Add(18, "R");
            listOfAlphabets.Add(19, "S");
            listOfAlphabets.Add(20, "T");
            listOfAlphabets.Add(21, "U");
            listOfAlphabets.Add(22, "V");
            listOfAlphabets.Add(23, "W");
            listOfAlphabets.Add(24, "X");
            listOfAlphabets.Add(25, "Y");
            listOfAlphabets.Add(26, "Z");
        }

    }
}
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace NumberToWords
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int input = 1;
            Console.WriteLine("Please Add Number Of Set: ");
            input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            GenerateList(input);
        }
        public static void CheckFile()
        {
            string fileName = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\Result\\result.csv";
            try
            {
                if (File.Exists(fileName))
                {
                    File.Delete(fileName);
                }
                File.Create(fileName); 
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
            }
        }
        static void GenerateList(int number)
        {
            var list = new List<int>();
            for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
            {
                list.Add(i);
            }
            GetCombination(list);
        }
        static void GetCombination(List<int> list)
        {
            var data = new Data();
            var listOfAlphabets = data.listOfAlphabets;
            var csv = new StringBuilder();
            CheckFile();
            string output = "";
            double count = Math.Pow(2, list.Count);
            for (int i = 1; i <= count - 1; i++)
            {
                string str = Convert.ToString(i, 2).PadLeft(list.Count, '0');
                for (int j = 0; j < str.Length; j++)
                {
                    if (str[j] == '1')
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            //var charArray = str.ToCharArray();
                            //for (int k = 0;k< charArray.Length;k++)
                            //{
                            //    try
                            //    {
                            int xd = Convert.ToInt32(str[j]);
                                    output += listOfAlphabets.Where(x => x.Key == xd).Select(x => x.Value).FirstOrDefault();
                                    csv.AppendLine(output);
                            //    }
                            //    catch (Exception)
                            //    {

                            //    }
                            //}
                            
                           

                        }
                        catch (Exception)
                        {

                            throw;
                        }
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            File.WriteAllText(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\Result\\result.csv", csv.ToString());

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A way to have all possible combinations is to use two stacks `inStack` and `outStack` in a recursive algorithm where single or paired digits are validated.

First `inStack` is filled with the input number digits, while `outStack` is empty.
Then call this recursive algorithm :

- If `inStack` is empty, return the content of `outStack`.
- If the first element of `inStack` is valid (not 0)

  - remove it from `inStack` and put it in `outStack`
  - call the recursion
  - restore the stacks
- If the first two elements of `inStack` combines to a valid value

  - remove them from `inStack` and put them combined in `outStack`
  - call the recursion
  - restore the stacks

A call log for `512` looks like this (stack head is on the right):

```
// Initial call
GetCombinations(inStack: '5 1 2', outStack: '')
│
│   // Pass '2' form inStack to outStack and call recursion
├─► GetCombinations(inStack: '5 1', outStack: '2')
│   │
│   │   // Pass '1' form inStack to outStack and call recursion
│   ├─► GetCombinations(inStack: '5', outStack: '2 1')
│   │   │
│   │   │   // Pass '5' form inStack to outStack and call recursion
│   │   ├─► GetCombinations(inStack: '', outStack: '2 1 5')
│   │   │   │
│   │   │   │   // inStack is empty. stop the recursion.
│   │   │   └─► returns 5 1 2
│   │   │
│   │   │   // Not enough digits to combine
│   │   └─► Skip
│   │
│   │   // First two digits combine to 51, which is invalid.
│   └─► Skip
│
│   // Pass '1' and '2' combined as '12'
└─► GetCombinations(inStack: '5', outStack: '12')
    │
    │   // Pass '5' form inStack to outStack and call recursion
    ├─► GetCombinations(inStack: '', outStack: '12 5')
    │   │
    │   │   // inStack is empty. stop the recursion.
    │   └─► returns 5 12
    │
    │   // Not enough digits to combine
    └─► Skip
```

Note that the content of `inStack` and `outStack` are reversed, a `Reverse` call must be done at some point.

The implementation will look like this:

```csharp
static IEnumerable<IReadOnlyList<int>> GetCombinationsImplem(Stack<int> inStack, Stack<int> outStack)
{
    // recursion end point
    if (inStack.Count is 0)
    {
        yield return outStack.ToArray();
        yield break;
    }

    var digit1 = inStack.Pop();

    // Try put one digit from in to out
    if (digit1 is >= 1 and <= 26)
    {
        outStack.Push(digit1);
        foreach (var combinaison in GetCombinationsImplem(inStack, outStack))
        {
            yield return combinaison;
        }

        outStack.Pop();
    }


    // Try put two combined digit (ex: 1,2 => 12) from in to out
    // First, test for the presence of a digit
    if (inStack.TryPop(out var digit2))
    {
        var v = digit1 + 10 * digit2;

        // Continue only if the value is acceptable
        if (v is >= 1 and <= 26)
        {
            outStack.Push(v);
            foreach (var combinaison in GetCombinationsImplem(inStack, outStack))
            {
                yield return combinaison;
            }

            // restore outStack
            outStack.Pop();
        }

        // restore inStack
        inStack.Push(digit2);
    }

    // restore inStack
    inStack.Push(digit1);
}
```

From this the conversion to letters is a trivia `(char)('a' + digit - 1)` will convert 1 to `a`, 2 to `b`, etc... no need of a dictionary.

Working code available [here](https://github.com/Orace/SO/tree/main/SO_74700616).
Online demo available [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RTlHA2).